Evitar que el navegador muestre un html guardado en historial despues de salir de la app
En mi aplicación web cuando se navega por las distintas secciones(html) tienen el botón de salir el cual los dirige al login.html y al entrar al mismo lo que hago es vaciar el localstorage() entonces cuando salen de la app, estando en el login y tocan volver en el navegador vuelven a la pagina de inicio pero en todas las paginas tengo este if:
if (localStorage.length === 0) {
    console.log('localStorage está vacío.');
    window.location.href = 'login.html';
}

entonces los redirige al login cuando quieren realizar alguna acción.
El tema es que aunque después de salir no puedan volver a operar no puedo evitar que al tocar el ATRAS del navegador estando en el login.html muestre la ultima pagina visitada en la app, solo la muestra y al tocar cualquier enlace interno te saca pero necesito que no muestre esa pagina.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Yussef
Tenes razón, disculpame presente la solucion a medias. Previamente usaba esto
 ///iniciofuncion para evitar que muestre la ultima pantalla despues de 
 ///salir
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Selecciona todos los botones de salir
  const salirButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#salir");

  // Itera sobre cada uno de los botones
  salirButtons.forEach(function (salirButton) {
    salirButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); 
     
      history.replaceState({}, "", "index.html"); // Reemplaza la página actual
      history.pushState({}, "", ""); // Agrega una entrada vacía (esto hace que la flecha de atrás no haga nada)
      history.pushState({}, "", ""); // Otra entrada vacía 
      history.pushState({}, "", ""); 
      history.pushState({}, "", ""); 
      window.location.href = "index.html"; // Redirige a la página de inicio
      
    });
  });
});
///fin funcion para evitar que muestre la ultima pantalla despues de salir

Esto agregaba entradas vacias entonces al ir hacia atras no se movia del login.html pero si apretaba 5 veces el ir hacia atras mostraba la ultima pagina visitada de la aplicacion. Esto no lo saque pero agregue la otra y funciona en todos los navegadores y en Android, ya está en produccion.

¿Revisaste qué contiene localStorage? ¿Qué te garantiza que el length va a ser cero?

Hola, si esto :                                                                                                              localStorage.clear();
console.log('Contenido de localStorage después del clear:', JSON.stringify(localStorage));                                                                                                 muestra esto :                                                                                                                          Contenido de localStorage después del clear: {}

Pasa que al presionar atrás la página se muestra desde el bfcache el cual almacena los valores del localStorage, esto quiere decir que toma los valores antiguos y por tanto localStorage.length === 0 no se cumple
Para detectar si la página proviene desde el bfcache, puedes usar el evento pageshow, entonces el código que muestras en tu pregunta lo debes reemplazar por:
window.addEventListener('pageshow', (event) => {
    if (event.persisted || localStorage.length === 0) {
        window.location.href = 'login.html';
    }
});


Muchas gracias Yussef encontre una solucion alternativa pero tambien probare esta que me ofreces. Muchas Gracias

Por si a alguien le sirve, en la siguiente función se evita que el usuario retroceda con la flecha del navegador cuando la lógica de la pagina lo requiera:
function dontback() { 
            window.history.forward();
        }

            window.onload = dontback;
            window.onpopstate = function () {
                dontback();
};


Tu respuesta me causa muchas dudas ¿estás utilizando algún framework ? ¿Tu app es una SPA?

Es una web, que consulta una api que trae  datos de la DB. tiene 8 archivos html entre los que se puede navegar con un token cargado en el localstorage para validar al usuario que se logeo.

Pero la pregunta es otra, es si usas algún framework del tipo vue, react, angular. O quizás uno propio, algo que modifique el history (que haga pushState). Yo acabo de probar tu solución en Edge y como sospechaba no funciona, salvo que haya modificado mediante código el history. Es decir, el evento onpopstate no se gatilla nunca al presionar atrás o adelante, salvo que yo haya realizado un history.pushState(null, "", "alguna_url") en algún momento

Tenes Razón, te contesto en otro comentario que puedo escribir mas.
